# Numerical precision in summing function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sum, flipud

When I run

```
import numpy as np

# Create small random numbers
a = np.random.rand(10)

# Check whether their sum and their flipped sum is the same
print(np.sum(a) == np.sum(a))
print(np.sum(np.flipud(a)) == np.sum(a))
```

the first statement is always true, whereas the second statement sometimes returns false, depending on the random numbers, and I have no idea why. I see this in both, Python 2.7 and Python 3.6. Interestingly, if I apply `flipud` twice like so:

```
print(np.sum(np.flipud(np.flipud(a))) == np.sum(a))
```

I always get True.

Edit: Some useful info on a related issue [from the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Comment: floating point operations are not amenable to exact comparison. The result can be different depending on the order of summation and the difference might be slightly larger than the machine float precision

Comment: Ok, what's the reason for this?

Comment: You can check the examples here https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/27975/21617

Comment: OK, that makes sense, so basically it's a rounding issue?

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that!